# Filtering dataframe given a list of dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following dataframe:

```
            Date            Site
0   1999-10-01 12:00:00      65
1   1999-10-01 16:00:00      21
2   1999-10-02 11:00:00      57
3   1999-10-05 12:00:00      53
4   1999-10-10 16:00:00      43
5   1999-10-24 07:00:00      33
6   1999-10-24 08:00:00      21
```

I have a datetime list that I get from `tolist()` in another dataframe.

```
[Timestamp('1999-10-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1999-10-02 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1999-10-24 00:00:00')]
```

The `tolist()` purpose is to filter the dataframe based on the dates inside the list. The end result is:

```
            Date            Site
0   1999-10-01 12:00:00      65
1   1999-10-01 16:00:00      21
2   1999-10-02 11:00:00      57
5   1999-10-24 07:00:00      33
6   1999-10-24 08:00:00      21
```

Where only 1st, 2nd and 24th Oct rows will appear in the dataframe.

What is the approach to do this? I have looked up and only see solution to filter between dates or a singular date.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want compare `Timestamp` without times use [`Series.dt.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html):

```
df1 = df[df['Date'].dt.normalize().isin(L)]
```

Or [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html)    :

```
df1 = df[df['Date'].dt.floor('d').isin(L)]
```

For compare by dates is necessary convert also `list` to `date`s:

```
df1 = df[df['Date'].dt.date.isin([x.date for x in L])]
```

---

```
print (df1)
                 Date  Site
0 1999-10-01 12:00:00    65
1 1999-10-01 16:00:00    21
2 1999-10-02 11:00:00    57
5 1999-10-24 07:00:00    33
6 1999-10-24 08:00:00    21
```